# preconnect resource hint not working in electron but works fine in Chrome

Tags: electron, chromium

I am trying to use preconnect resource hint in my app to pre-establish connections to the services. preconnect hint works perfectly in Chrome browser but when I try the same inside electron app it doesn't work.

I have tried the following different ways:

//< link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.bing.com/" crossorigin />

//< link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.bing.com/" crossorigin="use-credentials" />

//< link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.bing.com/" crossorigin="anonymous" />

//< link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.bing.com/" />

Most of the above methods work fine in browser but none of them works inside electron app.

Is there a way to get this working inside electron?

Comment: Welcome! This question looks incomplete. Which different ways have you tried? Are there any errors? Please update your question.

Comment: <link tag was not showing up correctly, so added // . Now you can see the complete question

Answer (score 0):

Preconnect is not currently part of Chromium's content module, which is what Electron uses. It's part of the chrome module. Therefore it's not available in Electron.

This was my conclusion of the issue I reported here: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/16476

See "chrome vs content" https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module for an explanation of the modules, and a non-exhaustive list of features that are chrome only. Note that "chrome" here refers to the browser chrome part of Chromium, and not Google Chrome.

I created this bug to make a case for documenting what is/isn't in the content module, for the benefit of Electron developers: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=924737